# Retrieve images from sdcard in android

Tags: android, android-sdcard

How can i retrieve images from sdcard to display on emulator in gallery format.i don't know how to do it.code is much better for me.Thanks in adv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.coderanch.com/t/443531/Android/Mobile/display-Images-stored-sdcard

Comment: Thanks for your replay.I've tried the example from above link.But i got error as "Process stopped unexpectedly "on emulator.i dont know why..